# Open3d Triangle Mesh fill_holes() method leads to crash

Tags: mesh, fill, point-clouds, open3d, triangle

I wanted to fill the holes in my triangle mesh with the fill_holes() function, after using the from_lagecy function. I have an array with 65 Pointclouds where I have to fix all of them:

```
currentPointcloud.estimate_normals()
mesh, densities = op3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(currentPointcloud,  depth=9)
densities = np.asarray(densities)
vertices_to_remove = densities < np.quantile(densities, 0.1)
mesh.remove_vertices_by_mask(vertices_to_remove)
mesh = mesh.filter_smooth_simple(10)
mesh = op3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.from_legacy(mesh).fill_holes().to_legacy()
op3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh], mesh_show_back_face=True)
```

The first pointcloud was fixed almost but after trying to use the method above on the second pointlcoud I get following message

```
[Open3D INFO] Memory Statistics: (Device) (#Malloc) (#Free)
[Open3D INFO] ---------------------------------------------
[Open3D WARNING] CPU:0: 6 5 --> 1 with 1218504 total bytes
[Open3D WARNING]     0x267506f5040 @ 1218504 bytes
[Open3D INFO] ---------------------------------------------
```

after this message my program stops and doesn't continue.

Did anyone had the same problem or understand the problem and can help me?

Comment: Can you upload the pointcloud files to reproduce the issue?